# Sklearn, ImportError : top_k_accuracy_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I had no issues while importing any of the other metrics (such as *accuracy_score*, *classification_report*) but *top_k_accuracy_score* triggers a import error. I ran my code on Google Colab.

Code snippet :

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, top_k_accuracy_score

print(top_k_accuracy_score(cat_y_test, preds, k = 3))
```

Error Message :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'top_k_accuracy_score' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)
```

I get the same error while running the example they'd provided in their [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score) as well.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got same error when using scikit-learn 0.21.2.

Try to update your scikit-learn to latest version (0.24.2 for August 2021) by invoking

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Or by using this command on google collab :

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

It resolve the error in my case.